# Show table of contents when opening PDF in Preview

Tags: macos, preview

Is there any way I can force Preview to always show the table of contents when opening a PDF? Most of the PDFs I use have a ToC, so this would save me the extra step from having to enable the ToC after opening the PDF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not possible to be set as default in Preview. The closest you can get to this is Preferences → Opening for the first time: Always show sidebar. However, the sidebar that opens is the default thumbnail view, not the TOC.

[image]

You can provide feedback to Apple regarding this at the following page:

- http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html